# GIT reset for particular directory and its sub directories

Tags: git, github

I am new to GIT. I have done some changes in source files and committed. When I try to upload I am getting conflicts in log files. I need to reset the log files.

**Is there any way that I can reset only log files?**

eg:- I have `/home/source` and `/home/logs`, I need to reset only `/home/logs`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
git checkout HEAD -- /home/logs
```

The `checkout` command replaces both the index and working version of files in `/home/logs` with the `HEAD` version of these files.  I am assuming that you are using some flavor of Linux.  I am also assuming that the most recent committed version of the logs files will be in sync with your remote when you go to push.

Comment: Thanks Tim, It worked. Using "git checkout" will revert the changes and "git reset HEAD^1" will make the file to point to head. This resolves the conflict.

Comment: You don't need to use HEAD - its default anyway. And -- is needed only if directory can be confused for branch name. In other words, just `git checkout home/logs` will work the same